# how to tell jackson to put unrecognized json data into a particular field while deserializing

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson-databind

My data model/POJO:

```
public class MyPojo {

    @JsonProperty("description")
    protected String content;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    protected String title;

    @JsonProperty("property")
    protected List<Property> property;

    @JsonProperty("documentKey")
    protected String iD;

    // Getters and setters...

}
```

However, my server returns json response in the following format.

```
{
  "documentKey": "J2D2-SHRQ1_2-55",
  "globalId": "GID-752726",
  "name": "SHReq - Textual - heading test",
  "description": "some text",
  "status": 292,
  "rationale$58": "Value of rationale",
  "remark": "Just for testing purposes",
  "release": 203
}
```

Here I've mapped the `documentKey` to `iD` and `name` to `title` of `MyPojo`. However, while using jackson's `ObjectMapper`, I get an exception saying `globalId` isn't recongnized.

The problem here is that it should put all such data fields (`globalId`, `status`, `remark`, `release` etc.) into the list of properties(`List<Property> property`). So I shouldn't tell jackson to ignore those.

How can I do that?

Comment: What is the full path of the `Property` class? Which package does it belong to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to use a custom Deserializer. This way you have total control on how to arrange the data

```
class MyPojoDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MyPojo> {

  public MyPojoDeserializer() {
    this(null);
  }

  public MyPojoDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
    super(vc);
  }

  @Override
  public MyPojo deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
    JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);

    MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo();

    myPojo.setId(node.get("documentKey").asText());
    myPojo.setContent(node.get("documentKey").asText());
    myPojo.setTitle(node.get("name").asText());

    // I just make a list of Strings here but simply change it to make a List<Property>, 
    // I do not know which Property class you want to use
    List<String> properties = new ArrayList<>();
    properties.add(node.get("globalId").asText());
    properties.add(node.get("status").asText());
    properties.add(node.get("rationale$58").asText());
    properties.add(node.get("remark").asText());
    properties.add(node.get("release").asText());
    myPojo.setProperty(properties);

    return myPojo;
  }
}
```

Then add the following annotation to your `MyPojo` class

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyPojoDeserializer.class)
public class MyPojo {
  protected String id;
  protected String content;
  protected String title;
  protected List<Property> property;

  // Getters/Setters

}
```

Then a classic readValue call should work

```
MyPojo myPojo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, MyPojo.class);
```